# User input if statements skipping

Tags: java, if-statement, input

So what I am trying to accomplish is having the user be able to order a item, so far just potatoes, and then to confirm the order using a "yes" or "no" input. What is happening however is the secondary input if statements are bing skipped over and the rest of the code runs. Can anyone tell why these if statements are not being implemented properly?

```
if(next.contains("potatoes")); {

        // Add in the quantity function later;
        System.out.println("\nAre you sure you want to add potatoes?");
    }
            if(next.contains("yes")); {
                System.out.println("\nYour basket:" + itemOne +" " +  potatoCost);
            }
            if(next.contains("no")); {
                System.out.println("You have not added " +itemOne + " to your cart.");
            }
            }

    while ( next.equalsIgnoreCase("exit") == false );

        System.out.println("You have decided to stop shopping!");
        System.exit(0);  
        }
```

}

Comment: Check the `;` after your `if` conditional expression. Should that be there?

Comment: Same for the `while`.

Comment: You're not asking the user for any input in these ifs at all, so what is the "are you sure" question being printed there for?

Comment: Also, I think you're missing a System.in.read after the confirmation message and you should use if else, or exact match, because if I enter yesno you would be executing both blocks.